# angular to webapi httppost call sends user object,Once they reach the webapi service properties under the user obj are becoming null(usrnm/pswd)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Hi i am new to Angular, 
Now i started with a sample login page which passes userEntity that contains username and password.
userEntity is a object/entity is webapi.

**Issue:**
When i make a http Post call for login button click i find the angular calling the webapi2 service where userEntity is not null but the parameters of the object i.e username and password are becoming null.

Individually the web Api2 works when i try to post the data from Postman /fiddler.
Not sure whats the issue when called from angular.
Any help would be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

**WEB API2 Code below:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("AuthenticateUser", Name = "AuthenticateUser")]
public HttpResponseMessage AuthenticateUser([FromBody]userEntity userentity)
{
    string username = userentity.username;
    string password = userentity.password;
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userLibraryService.AuthenticateUser(username, password));
}
```

**Angular Code below:**

```
factory.login = function (email, password) {
  return $http.post(serviceBase + 'AuthenticateUser', { userentity: { username: ’testuser@test.com', password : 'pass1335' } }).then(
               function (results) {
                   var loggedIn = results.data.status;;
                   return loggedIn;
               });
        };
```

Output:
I see the userEntity is not null but username and password are null once the request reaches the webapi2 service

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on AutenticateUser() method? Is that method being called? Is that single quote correct in this code `username: ’testuser@test.com', password: ‘pass1335'`

Comment: Actually I just kept them static for understanding in reality I just put my model parameters hence the problem of single or double quote do not come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try send an object with just the username and password properties:

```
return $http.post(serviceBase + 'AuthenticateUser', { username: 'testuser@test.com', password: 'pass1335' }).then(
               function (results) {
                   var loggedIn = results.data.status;;
                   return loggedIn;
               });
        };
```

also your example had `’` instead of `'`, not sure if it's a typo.

Comment: Thanks Gustav seems I do not need to specify the class name while sending the object that did the trick. Was stuck with this for long time . thanks a ton. Hope this thread would be useful for newbies like me